# Wait for ngInit before creating a method

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to use `this.user` variables, but unfortunately I must use observable in `ngOnInit` method to get them, so when I try to reach `this.user.username`, it shows undefined, because it doesn't loaded.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SettingsService implements OnInit {
  user: User | null = null;

  userSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private authService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSubscription = this.authService.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
      if (user !== null) {
        this.user = user;
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  changeUsername(username: string): Observable<{ message: string }> {
    console.log(username);
    console.log(this.user.username);
    return this.http.post<{ message: string }>(
      `${environment.apiUri}/users/${this.user.username}/username`,
      {
        username,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Can I kinda merge it together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `this.user` an RxJS [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) observable as well. So now you can push the `user` to the observable and it can be listened to in the `changeUsername` function. Then [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator could be used to map the `user` value to the HTTP request. Note that if the `user` value is still `null`, we return an RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) instead of the request. Try the following

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, EMPTY, Observable } import 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, take } import 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SettingsService implements OnInit {
  user = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);

  userSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private authService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSubscription = this.authService.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
      if (user !== null) {
        this.user.next(user);       // <-- push it to the observable
        // `return` isn't required here
      }
    });
  }

  changeUsername(username: string): Observable<{ message: string }> {
    console.log(username);
    return this.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(user => {
        console.log(user.username);
        if (user) {
          return this.http.post<{ message: string }>(`${environment.apiUri}/users/${this.user.username}/username`, { username });
        } else {
          return EMPTY;
        }
      });
    );
  }
}
```

#### Update from comment

You could still subscribe to `changeUsername` function as before. Only difference is the call is made only if the `this.user` variable isn't `null`. You could also return an error (eg. using [`throwError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/retryWhen)) instead of `EMPTY` and retry the request after some time using [`retryWhen`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/retryWhen) operator with a delay (eg. using [`timer`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer)).

Comment: Sure thing, thank you! And how do I subscribe to HTTP's responses and errors?

Comment: You could still subscribe to `changeUsername` function as before. Only difference is the call is made only if the `this.user` variable isn't `null`. You could also return an error (eg. using [`throwError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/retryWhen)) instead of `EMPTY` and retry the request after some time using [`retryWhen`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/retryWhen) operator with a delay (eg. using [`timer`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer)).